# Does Fire Emblem: Three Houses have any connection with the Harry Potter series?

Tags: harry-potter, fire-emblem

The newly released video game Fire Emblem: Three Houses features the main locale as a monastery that acts as a school. Within this school are the titular Three Houses: Black Eagles (red and black), the Blue Lions (blue), and Golden Deer (yellow).

Now there are obvious parallels here, not just in the idea of 3 school classes which students are “sorted” into (which is known to be something traditionally done in English boarding schools), but the colors and animals of the classes themselves run a very close resemblance.

Is there any word from the developers or directors of this game that these ideas have a connection to the Harry Potter series?

Comment: If you look at a Colour Wheel, "Yellow" and "Blue" are almost opposite each other, which makes them easy to tell apart.  The (British) primary school that I attended had 4 houses: Red, Green, Blue, and Yellow.  This was before the "Harry Potter" books existed - however these are very *distinct* colours, so it was easy to tell who was on which team in our house-coloured sports kits.  A nearby school had 5 houses named after Knights - again, their kits were coloured Red, Green, Blue, Yellow... and Purple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the Toshiyuki Kusakihar (company director at Intelligent Systems) there's **no connection with Harry Potter.**

> **RPG Site:** ***So, let's talk about the school side of the game... what was the thinking there? Was it inspired by any other school-based
> stories? The comparisons that seem most common among fans is to think
> of Persona or Harry Potter as a point of reference...***
>
> **Kusakihara:** *In truth it's not from Harry Potter, or Persona, or anything like that - it actually links back to an older Fire Emblem.
> Back a long time ago, we developed a game for the Super Famicom called
> Fire Emblem: Genealogy of the Holy War. When you look at the story,
> the three characters were from a monastery - they were friends, they
> worked together - and then they have to go to battle against each
> other. That's almost the same plot as that older game, if you look at
> that. So we had the image of this old game in mind before  - that's
> maybe our most significant influence on this project.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fire Emblem Three Houses interview: Intelligent Systems & Nintendo talk bringing the beloved strategy RPG series to Switch](https://www.rpgsite.net/interview/8711-fire-emblem-three-houses-interview-intelligent-systems-nintendo-talk-bringing-the-beloved-strategy-rpg-series-to-switch)</sup></sub>